# How to Send a hotkey in AHK after raising the finger on the key, not immediately just pressing it(LCtrl & RAlt)(<^>!)?

Tags: autohotkey

```
    ; this is the "1" hotkey to put PC to sleep :
    <^>!F8::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "Int", 0, "Int", 1, "Int", 0) 

    ; this is the "2" hotkey to go to a previous page in the browser :
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe msedge.exe")
    LCtrl & RAlt::send, !{Left} ;   
    #If
```

- When I use a browser ("Microsoft Edge") and press the "1", only the "2" is sent before the "1" And the "1" command is not sent , note that "1" works anywhere in the PC except in the browser.
- I would like to put the computer into sleep mode by "1" without exiting the browser or minimizing it, and without changing hotkeys.
- Is there a solution to do that? for example (send a Hotkey after lifting a finger from the key)
- I've tied this, but nor working :

```
    #If WinActive("ahk_exe msedge.exe")
    ^Numpad1::send, !{Left}
    LControl & RAlt::send ^{numpad1}
    #If
```

- Any help to do that? thanks in advance.
- I noticed that when pressing and hold the key, it deletes only one word and does not complete the deletion to the end, as in the case of pressing the original key(Ctrl & BackSpase)
- Can the deletion process be improved so that it is the same as the original Hotkey press?

Answer (score 1):

The [#If](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_If.htm#General_Remarks)(Win) directive is evaluated as soon as the hotkey is active or whenever the program needs to know whether the hotkey is active. Therefore it is not recommended to use hotkeys that are part of other hotkeys within it. Otherwise you have to repeat commands by adding an exception.

```
<^>!F8::DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "Int", 0, "Int", 1, "Int", 0) 

#IfWinActive ahk_exe msedge.exe ; #If has caveats

    <^RAlt Up::
        If (A_PriorKey = "F8")
            DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "Int", 0, "Int", 1, "Int", 0)
        else
        If (A_PriorKey = "b")
            send ^{BackSpace} ; to delete the previous word             
        else
            send, !{Left} 
    return

#IfWinActive
```

Comment: It worked well, thank you, but - When I am writing in the field and I want to delete a previous word using this command (bellow):

Comment: And `<^RAlt Up::` is better than `LCtrl & RAlt Up::`. See Note in [Custom Combinations](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/Hotkeys.htm#combo).

Comment: - I did it this <^RAlt Up::, but it didn't work,It only worked when I used (LCtrl & RAlt Up::) I noticed that when pressing and hold the key, it deletes only one word and does not complete the deletion to the end, as in the case of pressing the original key(Ctrl & BackSpase)
- Can the deletion process be improved so that it is the same as the original Hotkey press?

Comment: No, because of RAlt Up (the key has to be released first). As I said, its much easier if you remove the combination LCtrl & RAlt. Then you can combine LCtrl and RAlt with any key. Use another hotkey to navigate back.